# Can VS Debugger break on change of an Object ID? Similar to C++

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

While developing C++ having the ability to break at a specific address, when it is modified (e.g variable change) is very useful. Now I am using Object IDs in C# quite a bit, tracking states of certain objects.
Is there a way to actually break at the exact location when the value of an Object ID is changed?

Debugging a large 3rd party code base can be quite complex and I know that at some point somewhere in the code something causes the Object ID's value to change.

If it is a property, I can set a breakpoint there but is this the only way of breaking into change of Object IDs? Or do I have to search for every occurrence of the var and set a breakpoint on it? I mean if there are some advanced reflection techniques applied which modify the ID, then I'm out of luck with this and have to divide the code and narrow down the modification manually.

Just to be clear: I am not talking about a conditional break point at a location where `this == $1` etc.

Edit: Specifically: When I create an Object ID I am pointing to an instance of something, be it a private field, an instance of a class, a property of a class, etc. I am aware that this is not necessary a fixed location in memory, as in C++,  unless I pin the object but eventually something will access this memory. Let it be GC, or some other thread relocating objects or somebody access it via private field.
When this happens, I would like the debugger to stop, be it in user code, 3rd party code or even MIL.

Comment: So do you mean break when _property_ changes for a **particular** instance of a class, not all instances?  But you would like it to stop at _where ever_ it changed not just a particular line

Comment: @Micky, I updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: I understand.  Thanks for that.